# Dispatch Job from laravel to AWS SQS and make queue worker in lambda with python

Tags: python-3.x, laravel, laravel-5, aws-lambda, queue

I have **currently database queue setup with Laravel 5.8**
As per discussion with other experts **database queue is not recommended**.

So what I am trying to do is **Dispatch Job from Laravel to AWS SQS** and start worker in **AWS lambda with python3**.

Now, problem is that Laravel **by default serialize the data in JOB** and I am unable to deserialize it in lambda.

1. Is there any way to stop that serialization and add pure JSON payload to queue?
2. Is there any way to deserialize payload in python3?

Let me know if you need more details. 
Any suggestions will work.